# How to customize shell on a per route basis for ShellRoute or StatefulShellRoute of flutter go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Recently, go_router introduced ShellRoute and StatefulShellRoute that allow to easily implement such nice app features like 'stateful nested routes' by implementing 'shell' part separately to 'route' part within the builder with the following signature `Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell)`.

Problems:

- Now the build of a Page is split and it's much harder to coordinate (smaller problem).
  For example, how to access the generated typed route parameter?
- 'shell' part build does not have any idea about the actual route being built (larger problem).
  How to add a FloatingActionButton to a particular route if the Scaffold is built within the shell?

I reviewed the go_router documentation and examples, as well as any examples I found on the Internet. Everyone is just returning a Scaffold with a NavigationBar.